# Вернется ли MultiLineString в Yandex Maps API

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

В "Клубе API Карт" когда то был вопрос о том, почему перестал работать тип линии **MultiLineString**?
Там был ответ что такого в Документации к API нет и потому работоспособность не гарантируется, но топикстартер там говорил что в старых версиях API она работала.
Вернется ли этот тип линии в API Yandex Maps?

Comment: Вам с этим вопросом, проще в яндекс техподдержку написать.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это в техподдержку

Comment: Яндекс техподдержка недавно перехала сюда и об этом есть отметка у них на сайте: https://yandex.ru/blog/mapsapi/vremya-peremen-v-klube-api-kart-perenosim-tekhnicheskie-voprosy-na-stack-overflow. Так что замечания не считаю объективными.

Answer (score 2):

Добрый день, я из разработки API Яндекс Карт, в ближайших планах поддержки мультигеометрий нет, но мы думаем об этом.

Comment: Кто мы? Вы из техподдержки Яндекса?

Comment: Мы из разработки

Comment: Доплните этим  ваш ответ,  [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/759434/edit). Тогда он будет выглядеть аргументированным.

Comment: Marina St, спасибо за комментарий.